# What is the proper way to handle TypeError in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I am doing some simple calculations in a jinja2 template (subtraction) and would like to find a solution to handle TypeErrors in Jinja2.

This is what I have tried so far: To ignore unavailable variables during rendering, I subclassed Undefined() like such.

```
def silently(*args, **kwargs):
    return u''

return_new = lambda *args, **kwargs: SilentUndefined()

class SilentUndefined(Undefined):
    __unicode__ = silently
    __str__ = silently
    __call__ = return_new
    __getattr__ = return_new
```

This approach works most of the times, except for subtractions for example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "runScheduler.py", line 108, in <module>
dataFetcher.fetchData(**kwargs)
"/Fetcher/modules/dataFetcher.py", line 836, in fetchData
hmgReport.send_email(emailSubject,emailSender,emailRecipients,attachementFiles, context, 'reportTemplates/'+emailTemplate)
      File "/Fetcher/modules/reportEngine.py", line 190, in send_email
        print t.render(c)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
        return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "<template>", line 890, in top-level template code
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'SilentUndefined' and 'int'
```

I thought, I might be able to just ignore the "TypeError" Exception like such, but it's not working.

```
class TypeError():
    pass
```

This is how I do the rendering...

```
with open (reportEmailTemplate, "r") as myfile:
    reportEmailTemplateHTML = myfile.read()       
    #apply context to coverpage
    t = Template(reportEmailTemplateHTML, undefined=SilentUndefined)
    renderedReportEmailTemplate = t.render(context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first approximation, it sounds more logical and more in the lines of Jinja2 to move your calculation functions out of Jinja and keep them in Python.

```
def some_simple_calculation(*args, **kwargs):
    # handle errors here

t = Template(reportEmailTemplateHTML)
t.globals['some_simple_calculation'] = some_simple_calculation

renderedReportEmailTemplate = t.render(context)
```

And in your template

```
<div>{{ some_simple_calculation(arg1, arg2) }}</div>
```

Comment: I am bit lazy and would prefer to just ignore this type of error. Is this possible?

Comment: To my knowledge, it is deliberately not possible to handle exceptions happening inside Jinja templates, and I think that's a very good thing. Your code probably demands for a bit more structuration ahead of the templating step. You're trying to fight against the templating engine to compensate what is probably a minor omission a few steps earlier. Keep being lazy, just put your laziness at the right place ;)